# Deploy rails 7 and nginx in vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, devops, digital-ocean, vps

i've a rails project with importmap, scss, rails 7 and nginx.

i use a vps on digital ocean to deploy with docker and nginx.

my rails code stay here https://github.com/TryTech/try_tech

and my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 500000;
pcre_jit on;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
use epoll;
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
access_log off;
error_log /dev/null emerg;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m; 
    ssl_session_timeout 10m; 
    
    upstream web {
        server localhost:3000;
        server localhost:3001;
        keepalive 500;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name trytech.app;
    
        ssl_certificate  /var/www/certbot/live/trytech.app/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certbot/live/trytech.app/privkey.pem;
    
        location / {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Keep-Alive "";
            proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "keep-alive";
            proxy_pass http://web;
        }
    
        location ~ ^/assets/ {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
    
            add_header ETag "";
        }

}
}
```

i use docker-compose to up containers.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
  nginx:
    image: "docker.io/nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}"
    container_name: nginx
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
      #entrypoint: 'tail -f /dev/null'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./mime.types:/etc/nginx/mime.types
      - ./certbot/conf/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      # - public_rails:/rails/public
    depends_on:
      - web1
      - web2
    ulimits:
      nproc: 1000000
      nofile:
        soft: 1000000
        hard: 1000000
    network_mode: host
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.15'
          memory: '0.3GB'

  web1: &web
    image: "ghcr.io/trytech/try_tech:release"
    container_name: web1
    # volumes:
    #   - public_rails:/rails/public
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    network_mode: host
    hostname: web1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.45'
          memory: '0.5GB'

  web2:
    <<: *web
    hostname: web2
    container_name: web2
    environment:
      PORT: 3001


  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "docker.io/redis:${REDIS_VERSION}"
    command: redis-server --save "" --appendonly no --maxclients 20000
    hostname: redis
    network_mode: host
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.05'
          memory: '0.1GB'

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: "docker.io/postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"
    network_mode: host
    hostname: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/production.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/production.sql
      - ./postgresql.conf:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgresql.conf
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 10s
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.35'
          memory: '1.3GB'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  # public_rails:
```

I think that's enough context if you need more info. In short, my problem comes down to not being able to use the javascript and css that come from the server.

[image]

I've already tried several implementations, such as letting rails handle the assets or just nginx, but I haven't been successful, I'm not very experienced with both technologies, this is my first project. If you want to debug the browser in production, here is the url. https://trytech.app/

Thank you in advance for your time

What is expected is that the site consumes javascript and css correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with deployment. Fix your app locally first.

Manually add bootstrap pins to load from jspm:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.8/lib/index.js"
```

Downgrade `importmap-rails` to `v1` for now:

```rb
# Gemfile 

gem "importmap-rails", "~> 1.0"
```

`importmap-rails` `v2` is currently unusable a lot of the time because of this change:

*https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/pull/217*

Comment: Thank broh, this work to me.